# Making large numbers readable in code

Tags: c#

How can I make a large number more readable *in code*?

Right now I have:

```
long bigNumber = 11222333; //11,222,333
```

Commas in large numbers were invented a for a reason: readability.  The best I can come up with is this:

```
long bigNumber = long.Parse("11,222,333");
```

However, it seems "wrong"

Comment: In C# 7 this can be done using underscores, so you can write: `long bigNumber = 11_222_333;`.

Comment: How to do it with dynamic values coming from variable ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Oh, nice.  Can't wait!

Comment: @gamesmad yep, looks like it.  Not so much @ neverindingqs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hardcoded numbers should be avoided being explicitly in code, that's called [Magic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), instead you can have few possibilities marking the usage of that number.

**Constants**

```
public const int Megabyte = 1024 * 1024;
public const long Billion = 1000000000; // Or: (long)1E+9;
```

**Enum**

```
public enum MagicNumbers : long
{
    Billion = 1000000000
}
```

**Underscored** (C# 7), as @Lasse V. Karlsen mention in the comments.

```
long bigNumber = 11_222_333
```

Comment: I agree with the desire to avoid magic numbers. However, I usually like to supply default values in my classes to make implementation easier in "normal" cases.